# Doctrine annotations for migrations and ORM

Tags: doctrine, slim-4

I'm trying to setup a project using Slim and Doctrine. My problem is with the annotations.

If I try to run diff from migrations, it requires the annotations from my entities to be like this:

[image]

But, if I try to persist my objects in PHP ORM, it requires the annotation to be like this:
[image]

I'm not beeing able to find a way to configure doctrine to work with just one type of annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by when creating the Annotation Configuration for my EntityManager, set it to use the simple annotation reader, which is the last parameter here:

[image]